# Array String to Int android

Tags: android

This is my code:

```
            CSVFile csvFile = new CSVFile(inputStream);
            List scoreList = csvFile.read();
            String[][] baru = new String[scoreList.size()][0];
            scoreList.toArray(baru);
            Integer data[][];
            data= new Integer[baru.length][];
            for(int i=0;i<baru.length;i++){
                for(int j=0;i<4;j++){
                    data[i][j]=Integer.parseInt(baru[i][j]);
                }
            }
```

I want to convert the String `baru[][]` into an integer array `data[][]`. As you can see I have tried to convert it using `parseInt` but I recieved this error:
`java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to write to null array`

How can I convert string array to integer array? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: In your code you have `for(int j=0;i<4;j++){`  but shouldn't the variable be `j` in the check for length ? The way you have it now would create an infinite loop as `i` doesn't get incremented until `j` finishes looping and `j` would never finish because the `i` is not incremented to break the loop.

Comment: Oh i see, i miss that one, thanks for the help. I will try it first

Comment: `data= new Integer[baru.length][];` -> `data= new Integer[baru.length][4];`

Comment: is it baru.length indicate the length of baru rows?